# Sql to query builder - Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony

I wrote a query that needs to  take last 7 days and calculate spending amount for each day.

```
 SELECT
 DATE(transaction_date) AS TransactionDate, 
 SUM(amount) AS Amount
 FROM transaction
 WHERE type = 'spend'
 AND transaction_date>=  DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)
 GROUP BY TransactionDate
```

When I run my sql query it works fine, but I might be mistaking in my function I wrote in Symfony. It returns null and that is not the case with the query above.

```
 public function getWeeklyTrans()
{
    $date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime("-7 days"));

    $result = $this->getAmountRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->select('sum(abs(p.amount))')
        ->where('p.transactionDate BETWEEN :today AND :n7days')
        ->setParameter('today', date('Y-m-d h:i:s'))
        ->setParameter('n7days', $date)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();

    return $result;

}
```

Comment: the queries are not quite the same - one has an extra column and a group by, and uses >-= instead of BETWEEN. So seems to be less about Symfony syntax and more about the composition of the query itself...

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with the querybuilder, but shouldn't you use `->execute()` at the end instead of the `->getArrayResult()`?

Comment: It can be, but it's not logic here.  @Dirk

Comment: I have a problem in converting it. I can see a difference. :( @ADyson

Comment: well what is stopping you changing from BETWEEN to >=? And what is stopping you selecting another field? And what is stopping you adding a group by? Did you check the documentation of the query builder? They're all simple things, there should be examples there.

Comment: try using `BETWEEN :n7days AND  :today`

Comment: Still the same result. @Matteo

Comment: you miss the `type = 'spend'` condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you get the SQL from the Query Builder and copare it to your working Query ?
Something like `$qb->getQuery()->getSQL()` ?

Seems it miss few condition

- `type = 'spend'`
- `transaction_date>=  DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)` is not exactly the same condtion
- `GROUP BY TransactionDate` is missing too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much. I found a solution.

```
 public function getTrans()
{
    $type = Transaction::TYPE_SPEND;

    $result = $this->getAmountRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->select('sum(p.amount)')
        ->where('p.transactionDate >= :end')
        ->andWhere('p.type >= :type')
        ->setParameter('end', new \DateTime('-7 days'))
        ->setParameter('type', $type)
        ->groupBy('p.transactionDate')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    return $result;
}
```